# High load on simple Mongo find with indices

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, stream, database-cursor

I have a mongoDB I'm querying using NodeJS (running mongoose).

In this particular case I'm querying a bunch of collections and pipe the data as CSV into archiverjs to create a zip file. So I have an incoming request, the data gets queried using mongoose and a mongo cursor, piped into a pipeline which will end in archiverjs respectively the http response delivering the zip file to the user.

```
async function getSortedQueryCursor(...) {
  ...

  const query = MODEL_LOOKUP[fileType]
    .find(reducer)
    .sort({ [idString]: 'asc' });

  return query.cursor();
}


async function getData(...) {
    const cursor = await getSortedQueryCursor(...);

    return cursor
      .pipe(filter1Stream)
      .pipe(filter2Stream)
      .pipe(filter3Stream)
      .pipe(csvStringifyStream);
}

router.post('/:scenarioId', async (request, response) => {
    ...

    const archive = Archiver(...);
    
    archive.pipe(response);

    const result = await getData(...);

    archive.append(stream, { name: filepath });

    return archive.finalize();
}
```

As soon as a particular collection is in the game (the collection holds roughly **40 million documents**) the query lasts very long (**>15s**) and I can see the mongo process on **100% CPU** during that time. Even more surprising as the result set is empty (no documents matching the query).

It's a rather simple query:

```
items.find({ scenarioId: 'ckqf5ulg38gu208eecxlf95fc' }, { sort: { dataId: 1 }
```

I have indices on `scenarioId` and `dataId`. If I run the query on the shell it returns in **30ms**.

An `explain()` results in:

```
[
  {
    "queryPlanner": {
      "plannerVersion": 1,
      "namespace": "data.items",
      "indexFilterSet": false,
      "parsedQuery": {
        "scenarioId": {
          "$eq": "ckqf5ulg38gu208eecxlf95fc"
        }
      },
      "winningPlan": {
        "stage": "SORT",
        "sortPattern": {
          "itemId": 1
        },
        "memLimit": 104857600,
        "type": "simple",
        "inputStage": {
          "stage": "FETCH",
          "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern": {
              "scenarioId": 1
            },
            "indexName": "scenarioId_1",
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "multiKeyPaths": {
              "scenarioId": []
            },
            "isUnique": false,
            "isSparse": false,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexVersion": 2,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexBounds": {
              "scenarioId": [
                "[\"ckqf5ulg38gu208eecxlf95fc\", \"ckqf5ulg38gu208eecxlf95fc\"]"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "rejectedPlans": [
        ...
      ]
    },
    "executionStats": {
      "executionSuccess": true,
      "nReturned": 0,
      "executionTimeMillis": 0,
      "totalKeysExamined": 0,
      "totalDocsExamined": 0,
      "executionStages": {
        "stage": "SORT",
        "nReturned": 0,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
        "works": 3,
        "advanced": 0,
        "needTime": 1,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 0,
        "restoreState": 0,
        "isEOF": 1,
        "sortPattern": {
          "dataId": 1
        },
        "memLimit": 104857600,
        "type": "simple",
        "totalDataSizeSorted": 0,
        "usedDisk": false,
        "inputStage": {
          "stage": "FETCH",
          "nReturned": 0,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
          "works": 1,
          "advanced": 0,
          "needTime": 0,
          "needYield": 0,
          "saveState": 0,
          "restoreState": 0,
          "isEOF": 1,
          "docsExamined": 0,
          "alreadyHasObj": 0,
          "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned": 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
            "works": 1,
            "advanced": 0,
            "needTime": 0,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 0,
            "restoreState": 0,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "keyPattern": {
              "scenarioId": 1
            },
            "indexName": "scenarioId_1",
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "multiKeyPaths": {
              "scenarioId": []
            },
            "isUnique": false,
            "isSparse": false,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexVersion": 2,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexBounds": {
              "scenarioId": [
                "[\"ckqf5ulg38gu208eecxlf95fc\", \"ckqf5ulg38gu208eecxlf95fc\"]"
              ]
            },
            "keysExamined": 0,
            "seeks": 1,
            "dupsTested": 0,
            "dupsDropped": 0
          }
        }
      },
     ...
    },
    "serverInfo": {
      ...
      "version": "4.4.6",
      "gitVersion": "72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7"
    },
    ...
  }
]
```

It tells me (I'm not very experienced in interpreting those results) that the query is quite cheap: `"executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,` as it's not running a document scan `"docsExamined": 0,`.

Next I connected to the mongo server and ran `db.currentOp({"secs_running": {$gte: 5}})` to get some information from this side:

```
{
    "type" : "op",
    ...
    "clientMetadata" : {
        "driver" : {
            "name" : "nodejs|Mongoose",
            "version" : "3.6.5"
        },
        "os" : {
            "type" : "Linux",
            "name" : "linux",
            "architecture" : "x64",
            "version" : "5.8.0-50-generic"
        },
        "platform" : "'Node.js v14.17.0, LE (unified)",
        "version" : "3.6.5|5.12.3"
    },
    "active" : true,
    "secs_running" : NumberLong(16),
    "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(16661409),
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "data.items",
    "command" : {
        "find" : "items",
        "filter" : {
            "scenarioId" : "ckqf5ulg38gu208eecxlf95fc"
        },
        "sort" : {
            "itemId" : 1
        },
        "projection" : {
            
        },
        "returnKey" : false,
        "showRecordId" : false,
        "lsid" : {
            "id" : UUID("be3ce18b-5365-4680-b734-543d06418301")
        },
        "$clusterTime" : {
            "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1625498044, 1),
            "signature" : {
                "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                "keyId" : 0
            }
        },
        "$db" : "data",
        "$readPreference" : {
            "mode" : "primaryPreferred"
        }
    },
    "numYields" : 14701,
    "locks" : {
        "ReplicationStateTransition" : "w",
        "Global" : "r",
        "Database" : "r",
        "Collection" : "r"
    },
    "waitingForLock" : false,
    "lockStats" : {
        "ReplicationStateTransition" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(14702)
            }
        },
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(14702)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(14702)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(14702)
            }
        },
        "Mutex" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        }
    },
    "waitingForFlowControl" : false,
    "flowControlStats" : {
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to improve the performance or find the bottleneck in my application? As the load is high on mongo side and no documents are found/passed to the application I guess it's mongo having trouble ...

EDIT: I've logged the whole process from DB side using `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` and `db.system.profile.find().pretty()`. Here we can see that the whole collection (or am I misinterpreting `"docsExamined" : 39612167`?) is queried:

```
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "data.items",
    "command" : {
        "find" : "items",
        "filter" : {
            "scenarioId" : "ckqf5ulg38gu208eecxlf95fc"
        },
        "sort" : {
            "dataId" : 1
        },
        "projection" : {

        },
        ...
        "$db" : "data",
        "$readPreference" : {
            "mode" : "primaryPreferred"
        }
    },
    "keysExamined" : 39612167,
    "docsExamined" : 39612167,
    "cursorExhausted" : true,
    "numYield" : 39613,
    "nreturned" : 0,
    "queryHash" : "B7F40289",
    "planCacheKey" : "BADED068",
    "locks" : {
        "ReplicationStateTransition" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(39615)
            }
        },
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(39615)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(39614)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(39614)
            }
        },
        "Mutex" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        }
    },
    "flowControl" : {

    },
    "storage" : {

    },
    "responseLength" : 242,
    "protocol" : "op_msg",
    "millis" : 48401,
    "planSummary" : "IXSCAN { dataId: 1 }",
    "execStats" : {
        "stage" : "CACHED_PLAN",
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 48401,
        "works" : 1,
        "advanced" : 0,
        "needTime" : 0,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 39613,
        "restoreState" : 39613,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "scenarioId" : {
                    "$eq" : "ckqf5ulg38gu208eecxlf95fc"
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 6270,
            "works" : 39612168,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 39612167,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 39613,
            "restoreState" : 39613,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "docsExamined" : 39612167,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 39612167,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2151,
                "works" : 39612168,
                "advanced" : 39612167,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 39613,
                "restoreState" : 39613,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "dataId" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "dataId_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "dataId" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "dataId" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 39612167,
                "seeks" : 1,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The _cursor_returned by the `find` method is only a pointer to the result set data. To pass the data returned by the query, you may want to apply the `toArray` method and pass the array of documents around. About using the indexes, see [Use of Indexes to Sort Query Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index).

Comment: The reason why I'm using `.cursor()` is to use the results in a stream and not to load (the potentially quite large) result set into memory.

Comment: `return cursor.pipe(...` - Are you sure this returns anything? Is there a `pipe` method in the Mongoose APIs? The native NodeJS API says that the `cursor.pipe` returns null.

Comment: Yes. I get results. But very  slow. In other cases (different (smaller) collections) the results are returned and I get my CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As usual) it seems like the indices are not properly set. I've created a new (secondary?) index:

```
{
    "dataId" : 1,
    "scenarioId": 1
}
```

and now the query returns within milliseconds ...

EDIT: What still makes me wonder is that the shell query returned in milliseconds and the mongoose query took ages. Even though the queries seem to be identical (from my point of view) mongo treats them differently.